# Execution of sql command per line of text

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Trying to read an IP address from a file, plug it into SQL statement, execute and output the statement.

However, only the first IP address gets plugged into the SQL statement and is executed.

This is the code

```
$conn.Open()

foreach ($k in $file_line){

    $SQL = "SELECT dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME,
    [IP_ADDR1_TEXT],dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_DOMAIN_NAME, dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM,NAME,dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION, 
    Convert(VARCHAR(12),DBO.PATTERN.PATTERNDATE,107) as Antivirus_Date
    FROM dbo.sem_computer, [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER], dbo.IDENTITY_MAP, dbo.SEM_CLIENT,dbo.SEM_AGENT,dbo.PATTERN
    WHERE [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
    AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
    AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
    AND SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_AGENT.COMPUTER_ID
    AND dbo.PATTERN.PATTERN_IDX = dbo.SEM_AGENT.PATTERN_IDX
    AND [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '$k'"

    write-host $SQL

    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SQL,$conn)

    do{
        try{
            $rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

            # Read Computer Name, Computer ID and IP address from the Database into a multidimensional array

            while ($rdr.read()){
                $sql_output += ,@($rdr.GetValue(0), $rdr.GetValue(1), $rdr.GetValue(2), $rdr.GetValue(3), $rdr.GetValue(4), $rdr.GetValue(5),$rdr.GetValue(6))
                write-host $sql_output

            }
            $transactionComplete = $true

        }
        catch{
            $transactionComplete = $false
        }
    }until ($transactionComplete)

}

$conn.Close()
```

This is the output

```
SELECT dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME,
    [IP_ADDR1_TEXT],dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_DOMAIN_NAME, dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM,NAME,dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION, 
    Convert(VARCHAR(12),DBO.PATTERN.PATTERNDATE,107) as Antivirus_Date
    FROM dbo.sem_computer, [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER], dbo.IDENTITY_MAP, dbo.SEM_CLIENT,dbo.SEM_AGENT,dbo.PATTERN
    WHERE [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
    AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
    AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
    AND SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_AGENT.COMPUTER_ID
    AND dbo.PATTERN.PATTERN_IDX = dbo.SEM_AGENT.PATTERN_IDX
    AND [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '10.10.10.1'

H2UA1050K63 10.10.10.1 WORKGROUP Windows 7 Enterprise Edition Group Version Jan 05, 2015

SELECT dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME,
    [IP_ADDR1_TEXT],dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_DOMAIN_NAME, dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM,NAME,dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION, 
    Convert(VARCHAR(12),DBO.PATTERN.PATTERNDATE,107) as Antivirus_Date
    FROM dbo.sem_computer, [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER], dbo.IDENTITY_MAP, dbo.SEM_CLIENT,dbo.SEM_AGENT,dbo.PATTERN
    WHERE [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
    AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
    AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
    AND SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_AGENT.COMPUTER_ID
    AND dbo.PATTERN.PATTERN_IDX = dbo.SEM_AGENT.PATTERN_IDX
    AND [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '10.10.10.2'
```

The code looks correct, why would it stop executing and make PowerShell hang?

Comment: Side note: You should switch to using the join syntax from ANSI-92. It has been over 25 years since the "new" join syntax has been available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible cause for the hanging would be that anything going wrong with the execution of the SQL statement that generates an exception would set the $transactionComplete to false in your exception handler.  As long as that exception continues to occur the loop will continue to execute.

Assuming $cmd.ExecuteReader() throws the exception then you wouldn't get any output.

Try adding some code to output something within the catch block and see if you get anything useful there.

Comment: will troubleshoot this way